# Failed to configure spring-boot to support https for IOS application

Tags: ios, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot as backend server and iphone as the front end app. I need to setup https in the server side in order to submit my app in Apple Store. I did below configurations in application.properties in my spring-boot server:

```
server.port = 9080
server.ssl.key-store=/data/ssl/server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-password=123456
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
```

The IOS app got below error when connecting to the server through https:

```
error:Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error 
has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." 
UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would
 you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x610000257490
```

If I set the `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to YES in Info.plist in xcode, then everything works fine. But setting this flag to YES is not suggested by Apple. So I want to find why wrong with my SSL configuration. I believe that the issue is in the backend setting. So I did below check:

```
$ nscurl --ats-diagnostics httsp://www.nurse-go.cn:9080
Starting ATS Diagnostics

Configuring ATS Info.plist keys and displaying the result of HTTPS loads to https://www.nurse-go.cn:9080.
A test will "PASS" if URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: returns a nil error.
Use '--verbose' to view the ATS dictionaries used and to display the error received in URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:.
================================================================================

Default ATS Secure Connection
---
ATS Default Connection





2016-12-28 20:07:54.791 nscurl[27229:1903364] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
---

================================================================================

Allowing Arbitrary Loads

---
Allow All Loads
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions for www.nurse-go.cn

---
TLSv1.2
2016-12-28 20:07:57.904 nscurl[27229:1903364] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
---

---
TLSv1.1
2016-12-28 20:07:58.873 nscurl[27229:1903364] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
---

---
TLSv1.0
2016-12-28 20:07:59.843 nscurl[27229:1903364] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions for www.nurse-go.cn

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions and allowing insecure HTTP for www.nurse-go.cn

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy and Allowing Insecure HTTP
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled for www.nurse-go.cn

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed for www.nurse-go.cn

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================
```

You will see there are a few FAIL result in the above output. 
BTW, if I did the same check for a NGINX server with the same certification file in the same server.then everything passed. So I confirm that the problem is the spring-boot setting.
Does anyone know what the reason for this?

**EDIT1**

When I use browser to access the spring-boot server, my browser has shown green lock icon correctly. This means the spring-boot configuration works fine for browser but only has issue with iphone app.

Comment: You apache version is 2.4+?

Comment: I didn't use apache. Instead I am using embeded tomcat with spring-boot.